# Dlookup returning number as text

Tags: ms-access

The DLookup is returning number values as text.  Thoughts on what's either wrong with my code or reasons why that would happen?  I'm hoping it's something simple.

```
Sort: DLookUp("Sort","contacts_rank_CurrentRank","ContactID = " & [ID])
```

I've tried to Format as "General Number" but that doesn't transform the value back to a number

I've tried the below formula but that results in "Error"

```
Sort: DLookUp("Sort","contacts_rank_CurrentRank","ContactID = '" & [ID] & " ' ")
```

Visual of the data in the query I'm looking up the data from.  Sort Column in Contacts_Rank_CurrentRank
[image: Value to be dlookup up]

Value that is being returned with the dlookup
[image]

Comment: Set the format of the cells in the Sort-column to ```Number```.

Comment: It's always something simple.  Thanks,  I thought I had checked that but apparently not.

Comment: @Gowiser - Fixed on the query but the form is still showing it as text.  Also the properties on the field on the form aren't able to be changed to various formats.  Just Plain text and Rich Text are showing.

Comment: @Damian do some arithmetic operation with dlookup result which will convert text result to number. Like `DLookUp("Sort","contacts_rank_CurrentRank","ContactID = '" & [ID] & " ' ") *1`

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a dlookup here - a sql left join against that table will run at least 100x times faster.

But, you can do this if performance is not a issue:

clng(DLookUp("Sort","contacts_rank_CurrentRank","ContactID = '" & [ID] & " ' "))